# How can I identify and store all web elements while runtime?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**Requirement**: Perform actions like Select/click/enter on the newly created fields Checkbox/ button/Text box

**Example**: In my application, I have below fields on `version#1` code

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. City
4. State

In `version#2` code, the developer will implement new fields. How can I get those new field's web elements at runtime without manual derivation of XPath?

Comment: Please give more clear description of your problem

Comment: On my web page, I have 3 fields after deployment new required field is discovered, in this case, my script is getting failed because the script won't identify that 4th field web element. How can I capture  that 4th fields web elements while execute the script?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if this is what you need or I am misunderstanding your problem

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have 2 options:

**Option 1**

If you are using `PageObject` pattern with Selenium's [PageFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory), just add this new web element as a field with the appropriate locator

```
  @FindBy(css = ".new-element")
  private WebElement newElement;
```

**Option 2**

If you don't want to add new field for some reason, just get the element directly into your method

`WebElement newEle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".new-element"))`